# How with Inertiajs2 post request close modal dilaog on success?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

In laravel 9 / Inertiajs2/vuejs3 I have contact us form in modal dialog and when I open it on home page

```
http://local-bi-currencies.com/
```

I submit this form with inertiajs method

```
    formEditor.value.post(route('frontend.store_contact_us'), {
        preserveScroll: false,
        onSuccess: (resp) => {
            show_contact_us_modal.value = false
            Toast.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Your message was successfully sent. You will get feedback within next 24 hours !!'
            })
        },
        onError: (e) => {
            showRTE(e)
            console.log(e)
        }
    })
```

and action in controller :

```
public function store_contact_us(ContactUsRequest $request)
{
    $contactUs = null;
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $contactUs = ContactUs::create([
            'title'           => $request->title,
            'author_id'       => auth()->user()->id,
            'content_message' => $request->content_message
        ]);

        DB::commit();
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        DB::rollBack();

        return back()->withErrors(['message' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }

    return Inertia::render('Frontend/Home/Home', // Link to home page again
        ['' => $contactUs]
    );
}
```

as result new contsct is saved ok, but url of my page becomes url of store method

```
http://local-bi-currencies.com/store_contact_us
```

That is wrong url and it could raise errors next if to make some action.

I do not use axios here as I want to use inertiajs posting/validation functionality, which I would not have with axios
requests. If there is a way to return in return Inertia::render of store_contact_us method some fake vue file
without reopen whole hoem page and without changing of browser's urt into

```
http://local-bi-currencies.com/store_contact_us
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: return redirect()->back()->with(''success', 'Contact Saved Successfully'); or you can redirect to index route

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it works what I need, but could you please explain how "return redirect()->back()->" works in inertiajs requests ?

Comment: sure, redirect()->back() call your prev route, so bascially that return your prev controller inertiajs response

Answer (score 0):

you could redirect back as stated in the comments or, if you want to go to a particular page you could use `to_route` (simplified example):

```
$user = User::query()->create($request->all());
return to_route('users.show', ['user' => $user], 201);
```